# Laravel 7 Storage Image not loading

Tags: php, laravel

I have created new Laravel project as per their documentation
I have applied this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This creates a symbolic link to `'storage/app/public'` directory in `'public/storage'`

I have placed images in this folder in `'images'` and my actual path is `'storage/app/public/images'`
but my symbolic link path is

```
'public/storage'
```

now I have placed bellow image tag in welcome.blade.php

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/banner_1_en.jpg') }}" alt="testing">
```

but image is not showing.

I am new to Laravel and trying to learn

1. what I am doing wrong?
2. is this a safe way or place to store and show images on web?

Thanks so much

Comment: I am having same issue, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

the helper `asset` is for assets in the public folder, for the storage, you must use the class Storage, and its method `url`

Try this:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url('images/banner_1_en.jpg') }}" alt="testing">
```

Comment: not loading, its working with <img src="{{ asset('public/storage/images/banner_1_en.jpg') }}" alt="testing">

Comment: can you print the path with a dd()? or your current path is this string `'images/banner_1_en.jpg'`

Comment: here is result of dd();
dd(Storage::url('')); => "/storage/"
and dd(Storage::url('images/banner_1_en.jpg')); => "/storage/images/banner_1_en.jpg"

Comment: right, now try a dd with asset and compare the resuts please

Comment: I just copy and paste file there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218918/discussion-between-jonnathan-carrasco-and-mr-sh).